# Sharepoint 2019 classic UI - how to show % complete in bar rather than numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, javascript

I cant get the bar graph to work with new version of sharepoint, it worked in 2013 but cant get it to work in 2019(classic UI).
is there a javascript code that could work?
[image]

Comment: Just want to confirm, are you trying to achieve it in modern experience or classic experience? Are you not able to inject custom javascript in classic experience?

Comment: trying in sharepoint 2019 on premise, but using classic experience, i can inject javascript, but thats not what i used in 2013, so would be happy to try adding javascript,

Comment: What did you use for SP 2013, JSLink (Client side rendering / CSR)?

Comment: yes i used JS link for the 2013 version and tried on 2019 but no luck... the screenshot attached is from my 2013 site with the red bar.  not sure if the Admins have something locked down to prevent the js from working.